# Keras VGG16 lower level features extraction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am pulling lower level features from the VGG16 model included as Keras application. These features are exported as separate outputs of pre-trained input data for an add-on classifier. The conceptual idea was borrowed from [Multi-scale recognition with DAG-CNNs](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMnZ2oksXSAhXMVxoKHVxHDNgQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cv-foundation.org%2Fopenaccess%2Fcontent_iccv_2015%2Fpapers%2FYang_Multi-Scale_Recognition_With_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGFU9Ic1ZNFAd0sO6pE1B6dmPanVg)

Using the model without the classifier top, features at the highest level are extracted from block_5 pulling layer using `Flatten()`: `block_05 = Flatten(name='block_05')(block5_pool)`. This gives an output vector with dimension 8192. `Flatten()`, however does not work on lower pulling layers as the dimensions get too large (memory issues). Instead lower pulling layers (or any other layer) can be extracted using `GlobalAveragePooling2D()`: `block_04 = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='block_04')(block4_pool)`. The problem with this approach is however that the dimension of the feature vector reduces rapidly the lower you go: block_4 (512), block_3 (256), block_2 (128), block_1 (64).

What would be a suitable layer or set-up to retain more feature data from deeper layers?

For info, the output of the model looks like this, the add-on classifier has a corresponding number of inputs.

```
 # Create model, output data in reverse order from top to bottom
model = Model(input=img_input, output=[block_05,    # ch_00, layer 17, dim 8192
                                       block_04,    # ch_01, layer 13, dim 512
                                       block_03,    # ch_02, layer 9, dim 256
                                       block_02,    # ch_03, layer 5, dim 128
                                       block_01])   # ch_04, layer 2, dim 64
```

Comment: This interesting approach. Could you explain in more details how do you want to use this lower layers features?

Comment: Updated post with reference to publication. Merging of outputs is done in the separate classifier (as inputs) because then an optimization can be run on pre-processed inputs to see which feature layers add most to the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory error you mentioned comes from flattening a huge array which makes the number of units extremely large. What you actually need to do is to downsample your input in a smart way. I will present you some way on how to do this:

1. `MaxPooling`:  by simple usage of pooling - you could first downsample your feature maps and then `Flatten` them. The main advantage of this approach is its simplicity and lack of need of additional parameters. The main disadvantage : this might be a really rough method.
2. Intelligent downsampling: here you could add a `Convolutional2D` layers with huge subsampling (e.g. with filter size `(4, 4)` and subsample `(4, 4)`). This might be consider as intelligent pooling. A main disadvantage of this method is additional parameters need for this approach.

Comment: I am using a the pre-trained model network weights (transfer learning), so adding additional convolutional layers introduces other challenges. I will check what I can achieve with adding aggressive pooling layers to reduce the feature vectors.